# White screen on publishing app on Apple store when revienwing

Tags: react-native, expo

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
> in RCTText (created by Text)
> in Text
> in Text (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by Touchable)
> in TouchableWithoutFeedback (created by Touchable)
> in Touchable (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
> in AnimatedComponent
> in AnimatedComponentWrapper
> in Unknown (created by BottomNavigation)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by BottomNavigation)
> in BottomNavigation
> in ThemedComponent (created by withTheme(BottomNavigation))
> in withTheme(BottomNavigation) (created by MaterialBottomTabViewInner)
> in MaterialBottomTabViewInner (created by MaterialBottomTabView)
> in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
> in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
> in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by MaterialBottomTabView)
> in MaterialBottomTabView (created by MaterialBottomTabNavigator)
> in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
> in NavigationContent
> in Unknown (created by MaterialBottomTabNavigator)
> in MaterialBottomTabNavigator (created by App)
> in EnsureSingleNavigator
> in BaseNavigationContainer
> in ThemeProvider
> in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
> in App (created by withDevTools(App))
> in withDevTools(App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)

I tried to publish my app on Apple Store and they told me after splashscreen, a white screen appears and on my phone everything is getting fine.
bellow my code :

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import { ImageBackground,Text,StyleSheet,View,TouchableOpacity,Image,FlatList} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import Include_entete from '../includes/Include_entete';
import Couleurs from '../composants/Couleurs';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import {expo} from '../app.json';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
//import * as Device from 'expo-device';

export default function Fenetre_accueil({navigation})
{
    const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = React.useState({hits:[]});

    useEffect(() => 
    {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setTimeout(async() => {
            fetch("https://www.xxxxxx.com/application/app-recueil-sct/last_four_song.php", {method: "GET"})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => 
            {
                setData({hits:responseJson});
            })
            setIsLoading(false);
        },1000);
    }, []);

    if(isLoading)
    {
        return(
        <Animatable.View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}} animation="bounceIn">
            <RemotImage
                uri={"https://fxxxxxxx.com/ressources/images/logo.png"}
                desireWidth={200}
            />
        </Animatable.View>
        );
    }

    return(
        <Animatable.View animation="bounceInDown" style={{flex:1}}>
            <Include_entete />
            <ImageBackground imageStyle={{opacity: 0.2}} style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignSelf:'stretch'}} source={require('./../images/eagle1.jpeg')} resizeMode='cover'>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <FlatList 
                            ListHeaderComponent={
                                <View>
                                    <Text style={{color:Couleurs.text_info,fontSize:20,marginBottom:5,marginLeft:5}}>Bienvenue</Text>

                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Search',{search:' '})}} style={[styles.boxshadow,styles.card]}>
                                        <ImageBackground source={{uri:'https://xxxxxxxx.com/ressources/images/bible.jpg'}} resizeMode='cover' style={{minHeight:200}}>
                                            <LinearGradient colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.2)','rgba(0,0,0,0.8)']} style={{minHeight:200,padding:5}}>
                                                <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                                                    <MaterialCommunityIcons name="book-open-page-variant" size={45} color="#fff" style={{marginRight:5}}/>
                                                    <Text style={{fontSize:35,color:"#FDF2E9"}}>Recueil SCT</Text>
                                                </View>
                                                <Text style={{color:'#FDF2E9',fontSize:16,marginTop:10,paddingHorizontal:2}}>Cette application vous donne accès à tout le guide de cantiques de l'Eglise Soleil Couchant Tabernacle.</Text>
                                                <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse',borderTopColor:'#FDF2E9',borderTopWidth:1,marginTop:20}}>
                                                    <Ionicons name="arrow-forward-circle-sharp" size={40} color="#FDF2E9" />
                                                    <Text style={{fontSize:16,color:"#FDF2E9",marginRight:5,marginTop:7}}>Accéder à tous nos Cantiques</Text>
                                                </View>
                                            </LinearGradient>
                                        </ImageBackground>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>

                                    <Text style={{color:Couleurs.text_info,fontSize:20,marginBottom:5,marginLeft:5}}>Dernières mise à jour</Text>
                                </View>
                            }
                            data={data.hits} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} nestedScrollEnabled={true} 
                            renderItem={({item,index}) =>
                            (
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Chant',{Id:item.id})}} style={[styles.boxshadow,styles.card]}>
                                <ImageBackground source={{uri:'https://xxxxxxxx.com/ressources/images/jesus.jpg'}} resizeMode='cover' style={{minHeight:200}}>
                                    <LinearGradient colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.2)','rgba(0,0,0,0.8)']} style={{minHeight:200,padding:5}}>
                                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                                            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="microphone-variant" size={45} color="#fff" />
                                            <Text style={{fontSize:35,color:"#FDF2E9"}}>Chant : #{item.num}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                        <Text style={{color:'#FDF2E9',fontSize:16,marginTop:10,paddingHorizontal:2}}>{item.chant.substring(0,100).replace(/\n|\r/g,' ')}...</Text>
                                        <View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse',borderTopColor:'#FDF2E9',borderTopWidth:1,marginTop:20}}>
                                            <Ionicons name="arrow-forward-circle-sharp" size={40} color="#FDF2E9" />
                                            <Text style={{fontSize:16,color:"#FDF2E9",marginRight:5,marginTop:7}}>Consulter</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </LinearGradient>
                                </ImageBackground>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            )}
                            keyExtractor = {( item, index ) => index.toString() }

                            ListFooterComponent={
                                <View>
                                    <Text style={styles.text_footer}>version {expo.version}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize:9,color:Couleurs.text_muted,textAlign:'center'}}>Développé par <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>ifluxe</Text></Text>
                                    <Text style={{fontSize:9,textAlign:'center'}}><Text style={{fontWeight:'700'}}>Fruxgroupe</Text> en parténariat avec <Text style={{fontWeight:'700'}}>Soleil Couchant Tabernacle</Text></Text>
                                </View>
                            }
                        />
                    </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        </Animatable.View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text_footer:{textAlign:'center',marginTop:5,borderTopWidth:1,borderTopColor:"#7F8C8D",fontSize:10,paddingTop:1},
    container:{padding:10},
    card:{marginBottom:20},
    boxshadow:{shadowColor:Couleurs.text_muted,elevation:7},
});

const RemotImage = ({uri,desireWidth}) => {
    const [desiredHeight, setdesiredHeight] = React.useState(0)
    Image.getSize(uri, (width,height) => 
    {
        setdesiredHeight(desireWidth/width*height)
    })
    return (
        <Image source={{uri}} style={{width:desireWidth,height:desiredHeight}}/>
    )
};
```